# SonarQube on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have downloaded JRE, mySQL and followed these steps:
http://dev.mamikon.net/installing-sonarqube-on-ubuntu/

But when I start SonarQube by:

```
asd@asd:~/Desktop$ sudo sonarqube-5.6/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh console
```

I get this error and wrapper stops:

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2016.07.12 22:28:42 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /home/onat/Desktop/sonarqube-5.6/temp
jvm 1    | 2016.07.12 22:28:42 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/onat/Desktop/sonarqube-5.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /home/onat/Desktop/sonarqube-5.6/temp/sq-process9203755876203337834properties
jvm 1    | 2016.07.12 22:28:51 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2016.07.12 22:28:51 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/onat/Desktop/sonarqube-5.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/home/onat/Desktop/sonarqube-5.6/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /home/onat/Desktop/sonarqube-5.6/temp/sq-process7753077477656792686properties
jvm 1    | 2016.07.12 22:28:56 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2016.07.12 22:28:57 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: check /var/logs/sonar for error logs or in your location of sonar-qube folder for some more log which will point what happend there.

Comment: yes, there was a problem with my database connection. Thanks!